# twig: rendering child templates first, then passing to parent template

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller, twig, templating

I am new to Twig and need to check whether the way I use it in my MVC is the 'correct' way. I have a feeling that it isn't;

I want to have a controller for each region in my site and have each controller render their own twig template. I read about including twig templates inside twig templates such as:

**main.twig**

```
{% include 'header.twig' %}
{% include 'menu.twig' %}
{% include 'content.twig' %}
{% include 'footer.twig' %}
```

The problem with this is that I cannot run a separate controller for each region before the template is included. I would have to pass the variables for all regions as once to main.twig and I don't like to do that.

So I now do something like the following:

```
  $regions=[];

  //...preprocessing menu items here in a controller...
  $template=$twig->loadTemplate('regions/menu.twig');
  $regions['menu'] = $template->render(array(
    'home' => 'Go to Home',
    'contact' => 'Contact page'
  ));

  //...other regions...

  $template=$twig->loadTemplate('main.twig');
  echo $template->render([
      'regions'=>$regions
  ]);
```

And regions inside main.twig are then printed using the raw value: `{{regions.menu|raw}}`

This way I have full control over the data that is passed to each template which is what I want. However I have the feeling that I am now not using Twig the way it is supposed to, because I am saving rendered html in variables and then rendering it again.

If what I am trying to achieve is possible in a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass all data at once? The only other solution would be to write a `Twig_Extension` that is able to fetch the required data for each include.

Comment: several regions could for instance have the variable 'title' and if I would pass all variables as once to a main template, these would collide; or I would have to collect all vars in one deep mega object, it seems very inconvenient and also not pretty. What I am used to with all other MVC structures is to have every controller call their view with it's own variables separately, this division of functions is the most MVC-like way in my opinion. Thanks for telling about extensions, I will look into that. Also, do you see any problems with my current approach?(in terms of efficiency for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking it's causing a lot of overhead as you always will need to copy/paste the regions whenever you want to create a new page/controller. Idealy would be to use a main template with the includes and let your views extend from the base one.

---

*base.twig.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ page.title | default('') }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />
        {% block css %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block nav %}
        <nav id="main">
            {% for link in main.links %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </nav>
        {% endblock %}
        <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% block javascript %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
{% extends "base.twig.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

---

If you want to have a controller for each region you could create a helper class which calls all the controllers you need a returning an multi-dimensional array defined by the class name of the region.
This way your variables will never collide as you can access them by e.g. main.title / menu.title / title

*(code is just pseudo-code, did not test/run it, just to give you an idea)*

```
<?php
    $regions = (new \Project\Regions\Container())->addRegion('Main')
                                                 ->addRegion('Menu');

    echo $twig->render('child.html', array_merge($regions->getParameters(), [
        'title' => 'Hello World',
    ]);
```

```
    class Container {
        private $regions = [];

        public function __construct($regions = []) {
            $this->regions = $regions;
        }

        public function setRegions($regions = []) {
            $this->regions = $regions;
            return $this;
        }

        public function addRegion($region) {
            if (!in_array($region, $this->regions)) $this->regions[] = $region;
            return $this;
        }

        public function getParameters() {
            $data = [];
            foreach($this->regions as $region) {
                $class = '\Project\Regions\\'.$region;
                if (!class_exists($class)) continue;
                $data[strtolower($region)] = (new $class())->getParameters();
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

```
<?php   
    namespace Project\Regions;

    abstract class Region {
        public function getParameters() {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

```
<?php
    namespace Project\Regions;

    class Page extends Region {
        public function getParamters() {
            return [
                'title' => 'foo',
            ];
        }
    }
```

```
<?php   
    namespace Project\Regions;

    class Menu extends Region {
            return [
                'title' => 'bar',
            ];  
    }
```